# My has_many model is causing ActiveAdmin to look for a foreign key on the has_on side

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, associations, activeadmin

I'm new to ruby on rails (and ruby) and I'm trying to get ActiveAdmin working with my model. I've got a lot of the simple stuff working, but ActiveAdmin (on ActiveRecord) is giving me the following error and I cannot figure out why (I'm sure I've misconfigured something, but I don't know what):

> Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'assessment_styles.assessment_definition_id' in 'where clause': SELECT  `assessment_styles`.* FROM `assessment_styles`  WHERE `assessment_styles`.`assessment_definition_id` = 1 LIMIT 1

The AssessmentDefinition Model

```
class AssessmentDefinition < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :active, :endDOW, :endDate, :isForResearch, :name, :startDOW, :startDa>
  has_one :assessmentStyle, :inverse_of => :assessment_definitions
  has_one :consentForm

  validates :name, :endDOW, :startDOW, :endDate, :startDate, :presence => true

  has_and_belongs_to_many :courses
  has_and_belongs_to_many :groups
  has_and_belongs_to_many :behaviours

end
```

The AssessmentStyle Model

```
class AssessmentStyle < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :assessment_definitions, :inverse_of => :assessmentStyle
end
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops! I figured it out (with a little help from [Duane's Brain](http://duanesbrain.blogspot.com/2006/05/ruby-on-rails-hasone-versus-belongsto.html)). I was misunderstanding has_one vs. belongs_to, having confused it with the plain English sense of the word and not having realised what it was doing under the hood.